# Sorting a Vuetify DataTable based on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

In Vuetify 2.X it's possible to use the [custom-sort](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-custom-sort) prop of VDataTable to implement a sort function that uses multiple fields to sort the rows. Here's an example that sorts a table of people. When the name column is clicked the rows will be sorted by name alphabetically. People with the same name will be sorted in age order

```html
<v-data-table :custom-sort="sortTableRows" :headers="headers" :items="people" />
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    const people = [
      {name: 'Bob', age: 25},
      {name: 'Ann', age: 25},
      {name: 'Bob', age: 21}
    ]
    const headers = [
      {text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
      {text: 'Age', value: 'age'}
    ]
    return {headers, people}
  },
  methods: {
    sortTableRows(items, sortBy, sortDesc, locale, customSorters) {
      if (sortBy[0] === 'name') {
        items.sort((row1, row2) => {
          const nameDiff = row1.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(row2.name.toLowerCase())
          if (nameDiff === 0) {
            return row1.age - row2.age
          }
          return nameDiff
        })
        return items
      } else {
        // TODO implement sorting for age column
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Vuetify 3.X the `custom-sort` prop has been replaced by [custom-key-sort](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-custom-key-sort). However, this only provides access to the field that is being sorted, so there doesn't seem to be any way to implement the sort function above in Vuetify 3.X. Here's an example of using `custom-key-sort` to sort the names alphabetically

```html
<v-data-table :custom-key-sort="customSorters" :headers="headers" :items="people" />
```

```js
methods: {
  customSorters() {
    return {
      name: (name1, name2) => {
        const nameDiff = row1.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(row2.name.toLowerCase())
        // AFAIK there's no way to access the age field here
        return nameDiff
      },
      age: (age1, age2) => { /* TODO implement sorting for age column */ }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible in Vuetify 3.X to implement a sort function that uses multiple fields to sort a VDataTable's rows?

Comment: What is the main objective here? Sort by name + age when name header is clicked or having access to full row when the name column is clicked?

Comment: @SalmanA having access to the full row when the sort function of name runs is the main objective. Sorting by name + age was just a (bad) example of why this might be needed. The real sort function I want use requires access to multiple fields and is more complicated than this example.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is no Vuetify 3 equivalent to the custom-sort so far. However, you may use together the [sort-by](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-sort-by) property and [update:sortBy](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-update:sortBy) event to do what you want.

```js
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="people"
    :sort-by="sortBy"
    item-value="name"
    @update:sortBy="sortTable"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        itemsPerPage: 10,
        headers: [
          { title: 'Name', key: 'name' },
          { title: 'Age', key: 'age' },
        ],
        people: [
          { name: 'Bob', age: 25 },
          { name: 'Ann', age: 25 },
          { name: 'Bob', age: 21 },
          { name: 'Bob', age: 23 },
          { name: 'Ann', age: 31 },
          { name: 'Bob', age: 28 },
          { name: 'Ann', age: 18 },
        ],
        sortBy: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      sortTable(evt) {
        // Allows unsorting
        if (!evt.length || evt.length < this.sortBy.length) {
          this.sortBy = []
          return
        }
        const key = evt[0].key
        const order = evt[0].order
        switch (key) {
          case 'name':
            this.sortBy = [
              { key: 'name', order: order },
              { key: 'age', order: 'asc' },
            ]
            break
          case 'age':
            this.sortBy = [{ key: 'age', order: order }] // TODO implement sorting for age column
            break
          default:
            this.sortBy = []
        }
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

You can check on the [Vuetify playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are describing, it sounds like [this page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/sorting/) might be handy for you, there are both single and multi-sorting props for this element in Vuetify 3.X (it looks like they changed the way they handled it, from "custom-key-sort" to "v-model:sort-by"). Via the docs:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-model:sort-by="sortBy"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
  <v-code class="mt-4">
    <pre>{{ sortBy }}</pre>
  </v-code>
</template>
```

I may be misunderstanding the question/application, though.

Comment: multi-sort provides the ability to sort based on multiple columns at a time, but this is not what I need. I only want to sort based on one column at a time, but I want the sort function to have access to the entire data row